# one sudo for multiple terminals

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

Sudo root permissions are given for specific time, but only for one terminal. If I want to use sudo in another terminal in that time period, I have to type password again. How to force sudo to works across terminals?

Comment: Those are different user sessions. Would you like your sudo also affect other users (not you)?

Comment: run `screen` after you start a shell with `sudo`?

Comment: When I open two terminals in my window manager, from my (human) perspective it is one session. I want sudo affects every process run by me (the same user) using command sudo. I don't think I want too much. I really don't like when somebody gives me negative points, just because they never ask themselves such questions.

Comment: @jordanm: it will work, thanks. but after parent sudo expires, I will have to detach that screen and fire sudo in parent terminal again. thanks anyway!

Comment: Upvoting, if only because I'm curious as to how I'm viewing the opposite behavior: entering a password in one shell allows password-less `sudo` in other shells on the same machine.

Comment: @chepner - I do not see how that could happen, unless the user entered  directly went into a child process that somehow became a session leader, as in daemonizing.

Comment: so as I understand from yours comments, sudo grants permissions only to child processes. there is no global (like /var/sudo/lock_with_time) flag/semaphore ? it should be easy to extend sudo package. I will look into sources.

Comment: Running `screen` via `sudo` kinda defeats the entire point of `sudo`, doesn't it? You could as well use `su` by that point.

Comment: sudo on terminal, then exit, and screen, doesn't make child processes to react to new sudo commands reusing parent sudo authentication. I should tested earlier :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Time_stamp_file_checks

> Unless the timestamp_type option is set to “global”, the time stamp record also includes the session ID of the process that last authenticated. This prevents processes in different terminal sessions from using the same time stamp record. On systems where a process's start time can be queried, the start time of the session leader is recorded in the time stamp record. If no terminal is present or the timestamp_type option is set to “ppid”, the start time of the parent process is used instead. In most cases this will prevent a time stamp record from being re-used without the user entering a password when logging out and back in again.

Run `visudo` and then add a line:

```
Default timestamp_type=global
```

Alternatively, if you are using an very old version:

```
Defaults !tty_tickets
```

Comment: This is the feature I'm looking for! Great. (Disable it by `Defaults !tty_tickets`)

Comment: @TomekWyderka by running visudo or editing /etc/sudoers

Comment: @Prof.Falken by visudo. Actually, you cannot change sudoers file by normal editing (or maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: The `tty_tickets` option is superseded by `timestamp_type` available since version 1.8.21. Relevant values here are `tty` (default) and `global` (what you want): https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html